# Cannot set visibility after using ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, android-animation

I am using NineOldAndroids for animations.
Basically what am I trying to achieve is to apply some animation to button before hiding it.
so, I apply animations to my button and then call to setVisibility(View.GONE), but seems like it's not taking effect. The button is still on screen and handles clicks.
Should I 'reset' somehow the button state after applying animations?

```
    final Button button = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.user_to_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(AnimatorProxy.wrap(v), "alpha", 1, 0).setDuration(100).start();
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(AnimatorProxy.wrap(v), "translationX", 0, -v.getWidth()).setDuration(100).start();
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

if I remove the animations then it works as expected - hides button.

Comment: try it like this `button.setVisibility(View.GONE);` I had this issue before and I solve it like that

Comment: I tried, but still no luck.

Comment: Look into [Animation.AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.AnimatorListener.html#onAnimationEnd(android.animation.Animator))

Comment: @aneal, give me some more clue, please. onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) is never called for me, although the animation is not infinite.

Comment: Try setting the visibility after the animation ends via an `AnimationListener`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this before setVisibility after animation is completed:

```
anim.reverse();
        anim.removeAllListeners();
        anim.end();
        anim.cancel();
```

where anim is your ObjectAnimator